# Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized error

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to display the data in a `datagridview` in my c# windows forms project.  I keep getting this error

> "Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized"

is there anything i'm doing wrong here:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             try
            {

                SqlCommand db = new SqlCommand("select * from Tbls");
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = db;
                DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();

                sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();

                bsource.DataSource = dbdataset;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
                sda.Update(dbdataset);

            } 
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems that Habib, Aquinas and I have all given you pretty similar solutions. Did they work?

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign an `SqlConnection` object to your `SqlCommand` object.

```
db.Connection = conn;
```

Where `conn` is your `SqlConnection` object.

Initialize your `SqlConnection` object like so:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(/*Connection String*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new command:

```
SqlCommand db = new SqlCommand("select * from Tbls");
```

But, what SqlConnection are you using? You're not. You need to create a command with a connection. Generally you do this FROM a `SqlConnection` See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.createcommand(v=vs.110).aspx